# How to update newest yocto version

Tags: updates, yocto

I want to update yocto upper than 1.8.

But, I can't find way of update yocto.

Let me know site or search keyword.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current latest version of Yocto is 2.4-Rocko released in October 2017.

Yocto Project usually updates every 6 months.

Downloads: https://www.yoctoproject.org/downloads

Documentation: https://www.yoctoproject.org/documentation

Git: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/